# Movilizer Startup from another app on different platforms / app jump into Movilizer

Tags: movilizer

can you please explain how to start Movilizer on different platforms from another app? For instance:

- iOS? Via URL scheme?
- Android? Via intent? Via URL scheme?
- Windows Phone?

Any examples?

On Desktop I simply assume that calling the jar via java -jar ... will do the trick. Is there a symblink available when using the MSI installer to make things easier?

What are the options when starting? Is it possible to start a movelet directly? To jump into a category?

Are all platforms behaving consistent or is there anything I need to keep in mind that is platform specific?

Thanks a lot and best regards,

André

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding, you can start Movilizer from another app without any trouble. On iOS and Android I never try to do it, so I cannot explaint it nothing about it, but for example on Windows Phone I need to start Movilizer and other three different apps from a Socket, so I was using C# for this task, method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("movilizerPath.exe");
```

About the options when starting, yes, it is possible to start a movelet directly, using the **autoExecuteTimeout** attribute in the movelet tag. Value is an integer in range of −32768 through 32767 that indicates the number of seconds.

Value 0 deactivate the auto-execution.

Negative values automatically starts the movelet under this conditions:

- After the movelet has been downloaded, if the main menu is open at that moment
- After evey start of the movilizer client if the main menu is open at that moment

And the ositive values automatically starts the movelet under this conditions:

- After the movelet has been downloaded, if the main menu is open at that moment
- After evey start of the movilizer client if the main menu is open at that moment
- After returning to the main menu, if the main menu is opening at that moment

But remember, if you use that attribute with **timeout** attribute or with an epsilon screen only movelet it may result in usability issues.

An example of **autoExecuteTimeout**:

```
<movelet moveletKey="m1" initialQuestionKey="q1" moveletType="MULTI" autoExecuteTimeout="1" icon="1" visible="true"></movelet>
```

And about the last question... theoretically yes, all the platforms must behaving consistent, but that's not true in the practice.

There is a lot of examples, here you have someones of them:

- Screen types. Few screen types doesn't work in all the platforms. Type 14 (Single Select List View Screen) only works on Windows Mobile, lot of screens doesn't work on Windows Mobile (Google Maps SCreen, all the HTML5 screens, etc)
- MEL methods could be fail in some device on concrete versions, for example jsonToObject methods. It needs to be equal to null after finalize to use it, because if not it can be crash movilizer client on android and windows phone devices
- HTML screens has not the same look in all the devices. You need to controll it.
- Icons. Depends of the size and device, it could be really small, or big, in your screens.

All of this examples are using Movilizer 2.4 version, I cannot check all of them on 2.5.

Comment: Using auto executes for movelet start appears to be a workaround, but not best practice. This basically works around the startup parameters that should be available. 
The question about consistency was about startup parameters and not about platform specific screen types, html adjustments or icon sizes.

Comment: for instance: 
movilizer://?action=execute&moveletID
which can be used on Android to open Movilizer and start the Movelet with moveletID directly, correct?